# Build Debian Kernel Package from particular commit with modified configuration

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, compiling, deb

So far I figured how to build the kernel (I think) from the fork from particular commit as Raspbian OS `.deb` package. It's more less:

1. Clone the fork, switch to commit I want
2. Populate `debian` content via unpacking archive from downloaded by `apt source -d linux`
3. Change the version in `debian/changelog`
4. Setup `export MAKEFLAGS=-j$(nproc)` and export `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES='pkg.linux.nokerneldbg pkg.linux.nokerneldbginfo nodoc'`
5. Run `dpkg-buildpackage -b -nc -uc`

The problem starts when I want change in the kernel config. If I copy over any of `/boot/config-*` to that repo, the build fails with error about unclean sources in `debian/build/...`

Ubuntu guide says something about `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` but this doesn't exist on Raspbian OS Bookworm sources.

I tried to put configs in `debian/build/...` directly, but that doesn't built either.

I tried `fakeroot debian/rules setup` and added flags I wanted to configs above and the kernel built this time, but doesn't boot.

Which guide is up to date and actually works? Any step-by-step hints really appreciated.

For clarity I need to build `-image` and `-header` packages.